# Description length limit with glossaries

Tags: glossaries

Some of my `glossarie` entries have a rather long description.
After a certain number of carracters they stop being displayed by the
`printglossaries` command.
Here is an exemple producing this problem :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{short}{name={short},
description={a short entry}}

\newglossaryentry{long}{name={long},
description={
a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry
}}

\begin{document}
This one works : \gls{short}.
This one does not : \gls{long}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

How can I sidestep this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the glossary log file you will see

```
!! Input index error (file = gl55.glo, line = 2):
   -- First argument too long (max 1024).
```

Fortunately TeX is a macro processor so it is easy to have short texts standing in for long ones:

[image]

```
\newglossaryentry{long}{name={long},
description={\longdesc}}

\def\longdesc{a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to present more automatic solution to this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
%define new glossary entry key, description with no size limit
\define@key{glossentry}{description}{\def\@glo@ldesc{#1}}

%overwrite standard description key with new long description
%it also makes description key not mandatory when long description is defined
\renewcommand{\@newglossaryentryprehook}{
\def\@glo@ldesc{}
\def\@glo@desc{\@glo@ldesc}
}
\renewcommand{\@newglossaryentryposthook}{
%save the content of new ldesc variable and prevent it from expanding. Its important if we want to use fancy latex commands description
\protected@csxdef{glo@\@glo@label @ldesc}{\expandonce{\@glo@ldesc}}
%overide description field for this glossary entry. By using csexpandonce and csuse we prevent expansion and take into account that \@glo@label may have white spacess in it.
\protected@csxdef{glo@\@glo@label @desc}{\csexpandonce{csuse{glo@\@glo@label @ldesc}}}
%because \@newglossaryentryprehook is invoked after \do@glo@storeentry in glossaries.sty we need to save it all again ;(
\do@glo@storeentry{\@glo@label}
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{short}{name={short},
description={a short entry}}

\newglossaryentry{long}{name={long},
description={
a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry
}}

\begin{document}
This one works : \gls{short}.
This one does not : \gls{long}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

(I realise the question is old, but in case anyone is still interested I'm adding this.)

This isn't a problem with newer versions (4.0 and above) of `glossaries` as the description is no longer written to the file processed by `makeindex`. Now you're only likely to overflow `makeindex`'s buffer by having an extremely long label.

So your minimal example now works without any error from `makeindex`. If anyone else is encountering the same problem, the best solution is to update their version of `glossaries`.

Multi-paragraph descriptions are also now possible with `\longnewglossaryentry`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{short}{name={short},
description={a short entry}}

\longnewglossaryentry{long}{name={long}}
{a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
paragraph break

long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a long entry a
long entry a long entry
}

\begin{document}
This one works : \gls{short}.
This also works : \gls{long}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```